# Vocabulary list

Tags: semantics, vocabulary

I'm looking for a list of the most common words used in either English or Spanish preferably organised by semantic fields.

Can any of you point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists

Comment: For Spanish, Batchelor and Pountain's _Using Spanish_ has excellent semantic charts showing how various semantic spaces are divided between different words (especially verbs).

Answer (score 1):

The German publisher Klett Verlag has bilingual dictionaries called "Thematischer Grund- und Aufbauwortschatz Englisch" (for English) and "Thematischer Grund- und Aufbauwortschatz Spanisch" (for Spanish) that may meet your criteria. They are directed at language learners, and the frequency data are not included in the dictionaries (but the organisation by semantic fields is well-done).